# Docusign - eNotary - 1 Notary Multiple Signers

Tags: docusignapi, notary

We have a client setup, and they want to use docusign for all their documents.

During a eNotary process, they want to have for example:

Notary A -> Signer 1
Notary A -> Signer 2
**Notary A places seal (is this 1 seal or 2?)

Notary B -> Signer 3
Notary B -> Signer 4
Notary B -> Signer 5
**Notary B places seal (is this 3 seals or 1?)

In the UI under sandbox. I can do this just fine.  Using the api objects, I get the error.

{"errorCode":"ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS","message":"The specified envelope has duplicate recipients."}

I am not sure what is causing this, as the UI under sandbox shows that this is a capable feature.

Thanks for the help in advance
Jimmie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can have duplicate recipients, each instance of a recipient needs to have a unique Recipient ID.

If that's not the issue, can you post an [API log](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) that shows how you're constructing your envelope?

Comment: The issue I have with that is the NotarizeTab.  In the UI you place 1 for the notary, but he watches both signatures.  In the API, NotarizeTab has 1 recipientId, if the same notary has multiple ids, hmm, maybe thats not an issue.  Maybe legally, if its the same person, they would only need to put the seal on once.  I will try this and let you know.

Comment: That got me past the error at least, will work through the flows to make sure it works as expected.  Thank you